# How to Determine the Last Stock Price Before We Begin to Liquidate the Position on Interactive Brokers?

Tags: trading, interactive-brokers

I do not if it is me who is wrong or Interactive Brokers' employees who do not provide a clear information by phone about  *How to Determine the Last Stock Price Before They Begin to Liquidate the Position*

They say that for a Margin account to trade stocks the

$\text{Initial Margin} = 25 \% $ (This matches with the Buying power of IB that is 4 times the Equity)

$\text{Minimum Maintenance Margin} = 25 \%$ (This part should be different because the MInimum Maintenance Margin is less than the Initial Magin. **I will explain this with an example** )

According to them, the formula is:

$\dfrac{(\text{Cash borrowed}) /  (\text{number of shares})}{1 - \text{margin rate}} = \text{last price before liquidation}$

**Example of the apparent contradiction**

Suppose that you are a day trader who are interested in holding your position during the day, from 9:30 AM to maximum 11:30 AM.  In this case, and if you buy 2000 shares of MU at $\$50$ per share, you will be using all of your Buying Power, and you will be receiving margin calls for any drop on MU price because

$$ \text{last price before liquidation} = \dfrac{(\$ 100000) (1 - 0.25) /  (2000 )}{1 - 0.25} = \$50 $$

by the way

$\text{Cash Borrowed} = (\text{stock value})(1-\text{Initial Margin}) $
$\text{Stock Value} = 2000 \text{shares} * (50 \text{dollars per share}) = \$ 100000$
$\text{Margin Rate} = \text{Minimum Maintenance Margin}$

I would really appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39256/drawdown-on-stock-portfolio-to-hit-margin-call

Comment: Thanks @noob2 for the hint, but the question is different.